# SQL function gives error in some cases, why?

Tags: sql, mariadb, stored-functions

I have the following function which is run for each row as we generate data. If i run the function on a separate entry it works, but it gives error in the compilation process, so there must be some rows which break it, but I cant see what it could be.. Is there anything wrong with the syntax or something i'm not thinking about here? Any help or tips is appreciated greatly

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS xx__calc_date;;
CREATE FUNCTION xx_calc_date(date INT, id INT, esId INT)
RETURNS DATE
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF date IS NULL OR date = 0 THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE -- this is where the error lies
        IF(SELECT COUNT(b.TimeSort) FROM Booking b
              WHERE b.BookingId IN (SELECT DISTINCT e.BookingId
                      FROM xx.Events e
                      WHERE e.id = id AND e.esId = esId)
                        AND TimeSort < 86400) > 0
        THEN
            RETURN STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y%m%d');
        ELSE
            RETURN DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;;
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored functions/procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: If you get an error, why not share the error message?

Comment: Could you show us the schema of the both the Booking table and the Events table, please. 

Also, could you tell us what the error message is - to help us to help you?

Comment: the DBMS is MariaDB. The only errors I'm provided by the generation scripts are "xx_fact_trip SQLEXCEPTION" and a timestamp, so it's not very easy to understand or debug the issue :/

Comment: *The only errors I'm provided by the generation scripts are "xx_fact_trip SQLEXCEPTION" and a timestamp* Does you get this error during execution. not during creation? *it's not very easy to understand or debug the issue* Create debug table and insert the info about flow steps into it. *"xx_fact_trip SQLEXCEPTION"* What is current SQL mode? *FROM xx.Events e* `xx` is database name?

Comment: The error comes maybe a minute into the generation scripts. xx is the database name yes. We want to move data from xx to our database, and transform some of the data in the proccess, running over all the entries and performing functions like the one i posted. The SQL mode is: sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';

Comment: Consider passing a `DATE` in instead of an `INT` that somehow represents a `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

`e.id = id` is always true.

When in a subquery, you can leave off the table qualification *for the inner table*, not for the outer.

Suggest using `EXISTS ( SELECT 1... )` instead of `( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) > 0 )`

The expression that seems to be doing two "existance" checks.  Consider using a `JOIN` for such.